# What (if any) was the US position on the destination of the weapon shipment on the Klos C, seized in 2014?

Tags: united-states, israel, weapons, gaza, sudan

Israel [said](https://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/178328#.Ux3tzinn_IU) the weapons on the [Klos C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klos_C), boarded in 2014, were headed for Gaza.

> Speaking to the press at Eilat port, in view of the ship's deadly cargo, Prime Minister Netanyahu noted - in both Hebrew and English - that the assorted rockets, mortars and other munitions were meant "for fatal purposes against Israel to hurt Tel Aviv, Jerusalem, and even Haifa".
>
> Israel's Foreign Ministry has stated that it would file a complaint to the UN Security Council over the shipment. Iran has violated Security Council resolutions forbidding weapons sale from the Islamic Republic [of Iran] as well as arms smuggling to Gaza.

A UN panel (cited by Wikipedia via Haaretz) said they were destined for Sudan though. Did the US state their own position/conclusions on that issue, i.e. the intended destination?

Comment: This needs like 2 more tags LOL: Iran and UN. Alas there's a 5 limit.